# What is the appropriate way to show your progress in learning language using GitHub?

Tags: github, open-source, author

GitHub is a great place to share accomplished projects for veterans. It is also a good place for beginners to show their baby steps learning a new language. I am learning Java by debugging someones' else final code in tutorials. For instance, bot's logic in tic-tac-toe (original code is posted in GitHub) or a calc that displays "6.0-" instead of "-6" or crashes after a sequence "0/0=" instead of showing "NaN" (original code is posted in a blog only). Some day I will contribute to comunity, but for now the goal is to make it easier for the employer to evaluate my skills.

I want to gather my work in one place and give a credit to actual authors of the program. I considered using

```
//Corrections to bot's logic. Handling forks. Stepan's code
```

But that doesn't feel right. How should I proceed when authors post their stub on GitHub or elsewhere?

Thanks in advance,
Stepan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can submit a pull request and make your contribution to the project. Once you push it with a commit mentioning the changes you have made, the original repository owner can decide whether or not to merge the branch you have created.

From [[docs](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/)],

> Pull requests let you tell others about changes you've pushed to a
>   repository on GitHub. Once a pull request is sent, interested parties
>   can review the set of changes, discuss potential modifications, and
>   even push follow-up commits if necessary.

Comment: What if the original author posted his code elsewhere or on GitHub, but  long time ago and there are reasons to believe that he is not going to fix tic-tac-toe? After all, he is working on more serious projects now.

Comment: Depending on the "importance" of the change you are making, you could do one or two commits. If it is not very major, like the one you mentioned, I would probably shoot both changes in one commit.

Comment: @StepanLenevich Am I being able to help?

Comment: Let me clarify the question. One author posted some tutorial code on GitHub 10 years ago. Another author posted a tutorial code on his blog. This language is new to me, employer informally asked me to demonstrate some progress learning this language. What is the right way to proceed?        (I do contribute to GitHub in a different language, but that is a different story).

Comment: I am helping community using a different language (and a different nick name). Here I am trying to report my progress and clearly demonstrate, what contribution belongs to others and what is my part.

Comment: @StepanLenevich In such an instance, I would make a fork of that repository and take it from there.

Comment: @StepanLenevich It would be nice, if you could accept/upvote an answer if your issue is resolved. From [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), "Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved."

Comment: Yes, I will mark a solution. (I don't have enough points to upvote). So, How do I mark my changes if the original author didn't bother to post his code on github? I don't want to be rude like                                    //This code is mine, ha-ha-ha!!11

Comment: If you fork a repository, it makes a clone of the original in the state it is in. Now, whatever changes you make are in the cloned repository that you own. You can use the `Github` web interface and/or check out this [[link](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History)]

Comment: @StepanLenevich Sure thing :)

Answer (score 0):

This discussion suggests that:

(1) If the original author didn't post his code on GitHub, than just post it on your page. Give a credit to the original author by saying where the program comes from and placing comments like 
//Fixing [description of] problem (your nickname)
to indicate your contributions
(2) If the project comes from GitHub try to push changes first. If it didn't work in a reasonable time - fork it. You will have your own source code with smart bots and exception handling.